# Resetting Fstab on 14.04

Tags: command-line, fstab, partitioning

Heres the thing, my windows operating system 8 crashed due to a virus(so i assume)..It got the blue screen of death. I tried everything to recover it and nothing worked. So i decided to install ubuntu hoping it would bypass the problem. Well here i am using ubuntu..Heres my problem I get errors installing it so i had to do the (try ubuntu) option instead...I was trying to make it permanent through the (try system) Im almost done I just need to do some stuff to the fstab..But nothings right.. Please help me !!!! im going insane

Comment: When i try to ge fstab up this is what i get             (gedit:7525): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files So fstab text page comes up but its completely EMPTYY what do i do...

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your Windows crashed and you're trying to keep all of your data by installing Ubuntu...  **Great choice!**

These are the steps to follow:

(I will be saving this as I'm typing it so you can follow along)

1. Stop the panic! You're more likely to make mistakes when the adrenaline is flowing...
2. "Try Ubuntu" is just that: it does not leave any trace on your disk and you should not try to edit anything.
3. Install Ubuntu:

   You have a broken system!  Do not install Ubuntu on the broken system!

   Do you have an external USB hard drive? A 16GB USB stick? (8GB will do, but that's pushing it) Install Ubuntu on there and leave your broken Windows installation **intact** as a "data drive"

   Follow the procedure in [Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) from the official Ubuntu site.

   When you get to the screen "Installation type" click "Do something else"

   You will recognise your Windows disk and your USB disk. (hopefully, don't panic!)

   Create a swap file that is 2* the amount of RAM you have.

   Allocate as much of the disk as you can afford to Ubuntu

   Set that one as mount point `/`

   Choose your windows disk as mount point `/home` (yes, a tiny little bit of your windows disk will be written to, but all of your data will still be there!)
4. Reboot into Ubuntu (you'll have to go into the BIOS to boot from the external USB disk or stick)
5. Now you have a working system with all of your data intact, so your first action should be to rescue as much of the data of your Windows disk.  (Which is not a disk any more: it's a "directory" called `/home`)

   (It's technically not a "Directory" but a "Moint Point" under Ubuntu, but it serves the same purpose)

   Now copy all of your data off your Windows disk onto somewhere else. (or better even: make two copies!)
6. You've got everything rescued?  OK!  Now you're ready to chuck the USB disk/key, boot the CD again, wipe everything off the internal drive, and re-format everything (especially format)  Use EXT4 as the "file system".

Comment: Ok.so i already messed with try ubuntu..Actually i followed every step on this site until i hit the fstab issue..so i cant go further.http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/ so now that i messed with the terminal is there anyway i canreset the whole thing..also does this mean i have to keep the usb plugged in all the time>?

Comment: yes, it does mean keep the usb disk plugged in at all times... (I'll continue  editing my answer)

Comment: awe..lol thats lame...so whenever i want to use my laptop i need it in..is there anyway around that...

Comment: :P  This is just to give you a working system ASAP to allow you to copy your pictures, videos, documents, off onto another drive...

Comment: So i have a 32gb usb in right now.. im on the laptop can i just restore the system in system settings then follow your instructions? because the systems already on the usb...Thats how im online..

Comment: If you have all the data from windows that you want to a separate drive, then you can just reinstall on top of the main hard drive.

Comment: Well things are working..wifi is connected..seems fine..just a lil slow since ive been messing with it.. I got 5 disc looken icons on the left.. the first one says 481gb volume second says 249gb volume third says 15gb volume and the fourth and fifth ones just say label...idk if that means anything..

Comment: Idc about the data...i just want to boot up my laptop have it give me ubuntu..however its set..WITHOUT HAVING MY USB to be plugged in.. I want ubuntu to be the only software or at very least the main..

Comment: Seems like you're up and running!  Ubuntu is very different from Windows.  Forget that you're an expert on computers!  You're now officially an Ubuntu Newbie! (I was in the same spot you were about 9 months ago)

Comment: I understand, but if you're going to re-install (and reformat) everything, you need a backup first...  That is why I told you to do it this way...

Comment: Yea ok..so i messed with the terminal still..should i restore it....? I honestly only used it just to keep my computer working and not have to pay to fix it..

Comment: wait why do i need to back up? idc about the files i have on here.. I just want it to reset to before i messed with try ubuntu..It was a lot faster before i started messing with things.

Comment: No no not reinstall..Just restore on here..like the system restore.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get you to back up everything, then wipe and reformat everything starting from scratch thus "resetting" Ubuntu...

Comment: You can boot the CD again and reinstall ubuntu over the existing install... That would be the Ubuntu way of "system restore" ;)

Comment: Do you have team viewer? allows you to see my screen. and control it yourself.

Comment: But yes i have skype ferntheplant

Comment: downloading it now

Comment: i backed it up..but it said some files couldnt be backed up..

Comment: Then just boot the Ubuntu CD again and install it over it again...  I would move this to a chat room, but you don't have enough reputation to chat (yet)

Answer (score 0):

When you go through Install Ubuntu and get to the partition options do the following:

Choose option to do something else.

Delete All partitions

Create a 2gb Swap Partition at the beginning of the drive

Next Create an Ext4 using the rest of the available disk space and select the mount point root (/).

Once you have created the two partitions, highlight the second partition and continue installation.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: He wants to recover his data by installing Ubuntu and you're telling him to delete all partitions???  Please edit your answer ASAP before he starts doing that!

Comment: P.S. he should do "something else" but I would tell him to install Ubuntu next to his windows install.

Comment: Everything is wiped already. and i did something similar to that before going into to (try) mode. Gave me errors. Now when i check fstab it has nothing in the text..